# Why does fetching from 127.0.0.1 work but not from localhost within getStaticProps?

Tags: next.js

I am fetching data from my flask api that listens on port 5000 within `getStaticProps`. I noticed that fetching `http://127.0.0.1:5000/posts` works but not `http://localhost:5000/posts`. The same issue occurs for `getServerSideProps` too. But both urls work if I am fetching from client-side.

Here is my code:

```js
import axios from "axios";

export default function SSG({ data }: { data: any }) {
  return <div>SSG</div>;
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/posts");

  return {
    props: {
      data: res["data"],
    },
  };
}
```

And here is the error message:

```
error - AxiosError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:5000
    at AxiosError.from (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/axios/lib/core/AxiosError.js:94:14)
    at RedirectableRequest.handleRequestError (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:550:75)
    at RedirectableRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at eventHandlers.<computed> (/Users/tdawg/Desktop/axios-test/node_modules/follow-redirects/index.js:14:24)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:481:9)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  port: 5000,
  address: '::1',
  syscall: 'connect',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: -61
```

It doesn't seem like an axios issue as I am observing the same even with Next 13's `fetch`.

Why does `127.0.0.1` work but not `localhost`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `127.0.0.1` address specifies IPv4, and it looks like `localhost` is resolving to IPv6 (i.e. `address: '::1'`).

Presumably your software environment is not setup correctly for IPv6.

Comment: Thanks. It seems like node v17 resolves to ipv6 while older versions resolve to ipv4. `localhost` works when I downgrade to node v16.